# Pandas to_csv saving as NoneType and raising TypeError

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I am attempting to create an upload tool that takes an .xls file and then converts it to a pandas dataframe before finally saving it as a csv file to be processed and analyzed. After the file comes out of this code:

```
def xls_to_csv(data):
    #Formats into pandas dataframe. Index removes first column of .xls file.
    formatted_file = pd.read_excel(data, index_col=0)
    #Converts the formatted file into a csv file and saves it.
    final_file = formatted_file.to_csv('out.csv')
```

It saves properly and in the right location, however when I attempt to plug the resulted file into other functions that contain loops, it raises

> TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable.

The file is saved as 'out.csv' and I am able to open it manually, however the open command won't even work without this error being raised.

I'm using Python 3.6.

Comment: `to_csv()` writes the dataframe to a file and returns nothing. `final_file` would always be `NoneType`. Also, can you show the code or line of code that actually causes the error?

Answer (score 0):

`to_csv` returns `None` that's why you got that error
to maintain formatted_file, you could try this,

```
final_file=formatted_file.copy()
```

or

```
final_file=pd.read_csv('out.csv')
```

Comment: All the errors refer to the line I try to implement the csv file in my Python script.

Answer (score 0):

Pandas `to_csv` function saves the file but does not return anything. To loop through the csv file later you'll have to change the code to look like this.

```
formatted_file.to_csv('out.csv')
final_file = open('out.csv', 'r')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def xls_to_csv(data):

    # Read the excel file as a dataframe object
    formatted_dataframe = pd.read_excel(data, index_col=0)

    # Save the dataframe to a csv file in disk. The method returns None.
    formatted_file.to_csv('out.csv')

    # The dataframe object is still here
    final_dataframe = formatted_dataframe

    # The final file NAME
    final_filename = 'out.csv'
```

Your variable names are misleading

- Your `formatted_file` is in fact a data frame object
- Your `final_file`: it is unclear for me whether you want the `filename` or `the dataframe`.